# bones of my character are not saving

Tags: rigging, bones

I have a character with their respective bones and I am trying to put it in a pose to render, but when I make a change and then save my progress and I open the file again the bones are in their initial position as if I had not made any changes

Comment: you have to select all the bones (in pose mode) and then insert a keyframe with active keying setup to rotlocscale

Comment: please show some screenshots, share your file, etc... because it's hard to tell with so few informations